# How to use homebrew to install scripts

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have some git repos that have scripts in them (`bash` and `ruby`). Is there a way to use homebrew to tap those repos and install those scripts to `/usr/local/bin`? If so, how do I need to set them up?

Ideally for the `ruby` scripts it would check for dependencies (they’re `gems`) and install those first, but it’s not mandatory (should they be specified with something like `depends_on 'some-gem' => :ruby`?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, so I’ll post an example for each.

#### bash scripts

```
require 'formula'

class MyBashScripts < Formula
  homepage 'http://example.com'
  head 'https://github.com/user/my-bash-scripts.git'

  def install
    bin.install 'script1', 'script2', 'script3'
  end
end
```

#### ruby scripts

```
require 'formula'

class MyRubyScripts < Formula
  depends_on 'some-gem' => :ruby

  homepage 'http://example.com'
  head 'https://github.com/user/my-ruby-scripts.git'

  def install
    bin.install 'script1', 'scrip2', 'script3'
  end
end
```